# Is any second option to move rows in section in table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I implemented these three methods in my prog to move rows with in section.

Is mandatory to implement these three methods....

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath 
{

    if (sourceIndexPath.section == 0) {
        NSString *string = [arr1 objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
        [arr1  removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
        [arr1  insertObject:string atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    } else if (sourceIndexPath.section == 1) {
        NSString *string = [arr2 objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
        [arr2 removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
        [arr2 insertObject:string atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    } else {
       NSString *string = [arr3 objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
       [arr3 removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
       [arr3 insertObject:string atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    }
}
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
   if( sourceIndexPath.section != proposedDestinationIndexPath.section )
      {
       return sourceIndexPath;
      }
      else 
      {
       return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
      }
}
```

Is there any second option to move rows in section in objective c ......

Comment: Instead of remove and insert object in array, you should use replaceObjectAtIndex.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath {

   if (sourceIndexPath.section == 0) {
      NSString *string = [arr1 objectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
      [arr1 exchangeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
   } else if (sourceIndexPath.section == 1) {
      [arr2 exchangeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
   } else {
      [arr3 exchangeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row withObjectAtIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
   }
}
```